# Use '#' with method in codeigniter like www.mydomain.com/controller#method

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to call a method of any controller like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/controller#method
```

instead of

```
www.mydomain.com/controller/method
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use method like this?

Comment: Just to prevent page from refresh onclick

Comment: try with javascript, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

`#method`(hash) values not detected by PHP, even with `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`,

So It's not possible. You can detect the hash value with javascript `alert(window.location.hash);`  **OR** Use ajax to prevent page refresh.

Comment: Check this http://www.tinywall.info/2012/02/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu.html

Comment: @Kiranarya its all about ajax and jquery not related to PHP. And you can't trigger method with `#`

Comment: is it possible through routing $route['sendsms/#file2sms'] = "sendsms/file2sms";

Comment: @Kiranarya No, why not you use the javascript?